# How do I remove spaces in a string when adding it to a URL?

Tags: android, string, url, hyperlink, space

I've been working on a random string generator that displays the string at the top of the page. That part works fine. But at the bottom of the page I have a hyperlink the adds the string to the end of the url (to essentially google the string). My issue is the hyperlink stops after the first word in multi-word strings. For example, `youtube.com/user/dude` works fine, while `youtube.com/user/lady gaga` official  does not because the hyperlink only highlights **"youtube.com/user/lady"**, leaving the rest as just plain text.

How can I include all this without ruining the already displayed strings at the top of the screen? 
Thanks!

Here's my code for the hyperlink:

```
Resources res = getResources();
    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 
            String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
btn.setText("http://www.allmusic.com/search/artist/"+q);
```

Here's a picture of my issue:

http://i40.tinypic.com/2s0obr6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 
String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
q = q.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // remove all whitespaces
btn.setText("http://www.allmusic.com/search/artist/"+q);
```

This should do the trick. I've replaced all whitespaces with "", you can substitute anything you'd want though, an underscore "_" perhaps ?

Answer (score 6):

URLEncode your query string with [URLEncoder.encode(String s, String charset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to automatically escape your URL's:

```
String text = URLEncoder.encode("The Raincoats", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace spaces with `+`. That should do it. For example, this works: http://www.allmusic.com/search/artist/the+heavy

To accomplish that, you could do:

```
q = q.replaceAll("\\s+", "+");
```